# Global function with string arg in C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

EDIT: This was fixed

I am trying to create a global function that has a single argument of the string data type. However I can't get it to work. Here is what I have:

```
////////
//Func.h

#include <string>

#ifndef Func_H
#define Func_H

void testFunc(string arg1);

#endif

////////
// Func.cpp

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Func.h"
using namespace std;

void testFunc(string arg1)
{
    cout << arg1;
}
```

This does not work when the argument to be passed is a string, but if I make the argument an integer or char or anything else (that doesn't have to include any files to work), then it works fine.

Basically, what I want to do is have several functions in their own .cpp files, and be able to use them in a Main.cpp. My first idea was to declare prototype functions in a header file, and include the header file in my Main.cpp to use them. If you can think of a better way of doing this, please let me know. I'm not very experienced with C++, so I'm always open to improved ways of doing things.

Comment: This is embarrassing... Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

You forgot about namespace! in function header that declare function

```
using namespace std;
void testFunc(string arg1);
```

or you should write

```
void testFunc(std::string arg1);
```

or

```
void testFunc(std::string &arg1); // pointer to string object
```

or if you function will not change the object

```
void testFunc(const std::string &arg1);
```

And don't forget about Func.cpp, function implementation must have the same arguments as declaration, to call it from another file.